# WP7 Multiple controls animation problem

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am storing a set of controls in an array and i am trying to animate all the controls one by one in a loop but I can see only last one animating ?

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    var sb = new Storyboard();
                    sb = CreateStoryboard(1.0, 0.0, this.Lights[0, i]);
                    sb.Begin();
                });
               }


private Storyboard CreateStoryboard(double from, double to, DependencyObject targetControl)
        {
            Storyboard result = new Storyboard();

            DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();
            animation.From = from;
            animation.To = to;
            animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            animation.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            animation.AutoReverse = false;
            Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, targetControl);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(UIElement.OpacityProperty));

            result.Children.Add(animation);
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Does this change in approach mean your last question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384159/wp7-ui-updating-issue) is not longer valid?

Comment: Please note that Windows Phone 7 uses a version of Silverlight 3, not 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm at a loss to explain that behaviour.  Without the `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` you would just get all items fading at the same time.  However I can't see why you wouldn't get the same when using `BeginInvoke`.  Still neither is what you are after.  You need to sequence the animations one after another.

Probably the best way to do this is to use a single StoryBoard with multiple animations, the *sequencing* of animations is afterall the whole point of a **Storyboard**.

```
    private DoubleAnimation CreateAnimation(double from, double to, DependencyObject targetControl, int index)
    {
        DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();
        animation.From = from;
        animation.To = to;
        animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        animation.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1 * index);
        animation.AutoReverse = false;
        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, targetControl);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(UIElement.OpacityProperty));

        return animation;
    }
```

Note the extra `index` parameter and that is use to specify when the animation should begin.

Now your code is simply:-

```
var sb = new Storyboard();     

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)     
{     
    sb.Children.Add(CreateAnimation(1.0, 0.0, this.Lights[0, i], i);     
}

sb.Begin();
```